# Issues with Magento Checkout

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1.7, magento-1.8, checkout, onepage-checkout

So I'm on Magento 1.6.2 and I am having issues with checkout. For some reasons I am stuck on the first step(Billing) on checkout. Whenever I try and click the continue button checkout will not go to the next step. Can anyone help please?

[image]

Comment: Did you get any error (PHP, JS, ..) ?

Comment: @Kozame The only thing I see in the error logs is this:
2018-08-24T14:51:43+00:00 ERR (3): Deprecated functionality: iconv_set_encoding(): Use of iconv.internal_encoding is deprecated  in /opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs/includes/src/Zend_Validate_Hostname.php on line 617

Comment: That works before ? Did you do any code modification ? Did you check all your log (system.log, exception.log, the console of your browser, ...) ?

Comment: @Kozame Yeah it all worked before. I checked everything and there's no other message.

Comment: you can show any image bugs

Comment: @NguyễnHồngQuân Getting this error now.

Comment: @NguyễnHồngQuân updated my post with image.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add a **formkey** :

> ```
> <?php echo $this->getBlockHtml('formkey'); ?>
> ```

after `<form` tag in :

> app/design/frontend/{package}/{theme}/template/checkout/onepage/billing.phtml
>
> app/design/frontend/{package}/{theme}/template/checkout/multishipping/billing.phtml
>
> app/design/frontend/{package}/{theme}/template/persistent/checkout/onepage/billing.phtml